# How can i select the whole row/line when clicking on a line in a textbox in C#

Tags: c#

For example I have a Textbox that contains the following:

```
aaa
bbb
ccc
```

now when i click on one of the a's on the first row, i want it to automatically select the whole and then copy it to another Textbox, how would i go around doing this.
Just to clarify, If i select a on the first row, aaa will be copied to another Textbox.

By the way this is a Rich textbox.

I put the beginning of the code below because it would not allow me to post the question for some reason.

```
Private void richTextBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
}
```

Comment: Do you actually need a textbox?? What I understand in your question, is that you won't let the user type in the textbox. In this case, you should replace your textbox by a simple listbox!

Comment: WinForm? WPF? ASP.Net? WTF.Net?

Comment: Steve thank you, I am such an idiot, I can't believe i haven't done that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// now you need to know what character index starts that line
var start = textBox.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine();

// and with the line already in hand we can calculate the ending index
var end = start + textBox.Lines(textBox.GetLineFromCharIndex(start)).Length;

// now select that range
textBox.Select(start, end);
```

Comment: Thanks! But i am unable to use .length on line.

Comment: I know.. really old post, but came up first on Google search... couldn't get the code to work, but just needed slight tweak.. 

end = (textBox.Lines[textBox.GetLineFromCharIndex(start)]).Length;           

basically don't add the "start +" to end.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
this.textBox1.GetLineFromCharIndex(this.textBox1.SelectionStart) + 1;
```

source :
 http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/6f100a25-44ec-44d7-b73c-0b62f89e934d/how-to-detect-current-line-in-a-textbox

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do something similar with a RichTextBox control, and then I happily discovered the ShowSelectionMargin property. When set to True, it gives you a left margin that you can click on for selecting the whole line (which happened to be exactly the behavior I wanted).

Not exactly what was asked for by the OP, but perhaps relevant to others looking for this kind of functionality.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub SelectFullLine(ByVal sender As TextBox)
    Dim box = CType(sender, TextBox)
    box.Focus()

    Dim b = box.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine()

    While box.GetPositionFromCharIndex(box.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine()).Y = box.GetPositionFromCharIndex(b).Y
        b = b + 1
    End While

    If box.Text.Chars(b - 1) = Chr(10) Then
        b = b - box.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine() - 1
    Else
        b = b - box.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine()
    End If
    box.Select(box.GetFirstCharIndexOfCurrentLine(), b)

End Sub
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.